# Add 'check' class to previous item after clicking a button

Tags: javascript, angular, click, dom-events

I'm trying to add a class **unlocked** on **previous item** when I click  button and my **current** moves to next item, but I can't figure out how. Current functionality is working fine but I want to add unlocked class. Any help would be great.

```
<ul>
        <li class="locked" *ngFor="let subLecture of lectureList; let j = index"
            [ngClass]="{ 'current': lectureIndex == j}"
            (click)="lectureItemClick(j)">
          <a>{{subLecture}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <button (click)="nextLectureSecond()">Next</button>
```

**Here's an attached demo:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cdiev5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another condition as well in the `[ngClass]`, something like `'unlocked': lectureIndex > j` if you wish to apply the class to all the previous items.

See if this helps:

```
<ul>
    <li class="locked" *ngFor="let subLecture of lectureList; let j = index"
        [ngClass]="{ 'current': lectureIndex == j, 'unlocked': lectureIndex > j}"
        (click)="lectureItemClick(j)">
      <a>{{subLecture}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Similarly, you can change the logic to suit your scenario.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-62422113

Comment: This is quite helpful but Is there any way that when I click on list item it won't remove the class we're adding i.e, 'unlocked'? Cuz it removes it when I click on any of the li

Comment: Sure, glad to help.
I modified the code and the stackblitz example. Please do accept the answer the if it helped.

Comment: No no, maybe you misunderstood. I want current class on the item which is selected, now it's not removing current too, previous behavior was okay but i just wanted to have 'unlocked' class removed.Hope you understand now

Comment: Ok, that means once the lecture is unlocked, you want to keep the class `unlocked` applied to them. For that, we would have to save the state somewhere. I modified my stackblitz for this scenario. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Although It's not recommended to use the `document` keyword if you are using server-side rendering, you can use another workaround as well, you can follow the below way as well.

```
<li class="locked" *ngFor="let subLecture of lectureList; let j = index"      [id]="j">
....
</li>

nextLectureSecond() {
    ....
    let ele = document.getElementById(this.lectureIndex.toString());
    (<HTMLParagraphElement>ele).classList.add("unlocked");
    const a = this.lectureIndex++;
    ....
}
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1m8alu?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just the previous item?
Change your ng-class declaration like this : 
`[ngClass]="{ 'current': lectureIndex == j, 'unlocked' : (lectureIndex!=0 && lectureIndex - 1 == j )}"`
[Se here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vb7iyv)

Comment: Not just the previous, every item I pass through